# What's the difference between /proc and /proc/ (with a trailing slash)?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I try using `tar` to backup my files. With `--exclude=/proc/`, the archive contains files under /proc, and `--exclude=/proc` does not. What causes the difference?

P.S. The shell I use is Bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no major difference between using a trailing slash or not in general for a directory, except in symlink handling. See [Open Group Base Specifications, 4.11 Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) (also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919) at Unix SE).

As GNU tar is concerned: a trailing slash is simply not handled in `--exclude` patterns, as you've noticed. The difference is simply caused by its specific source code, if one should point to something :-) . See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/219964/tar-exclude-not-working) at Server Fault SE (though it does not give much detail - it merely states the fact). See [this mail thread](http://openbsd.monkey.org/tech/200503/msg00049.html) for some related information. A clue might be found in this passage (though I'm not entirely sure what to make of it):

> Otto Moerbeek wrote:
>
> This is the piece of code that *is* relevant:
>
> ```
>             /*
>              * Some programs that create ustar archives append a '/'
>              * to the pathname for directories. This clearly violates
>              * ustar specs, but we will silently strip it off anyway. 
>              */
>             if (arcn-> name[arcn-> nlen - 1] == '/')
>                     arcn-> name[--arcn-> nlen] = '\0';
> ```
>
> As you can see with hexdump -C of archives created by gtar, gtar is
>   such a program. I do not feel like changing tar just to accomodate
>   non-conforming programs.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, it's down to the convention of the program. With (GNU) `tar` it's a little inconsistent because a trailing /  does not change *included* directories. The behaviour is partly explained [here](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/tar/manual/html_node/controlling-pattern_002dmatching.html) "*patterns and names are used as-is*". Excludes can match any part of a name (unless you use `--anchor`).

Documentation isn't clear that there is a difference, or why.

Internally, the reason a trailing / doesn't match in an exclude is that `tar` uses `opendir(3)`, `readdir(3)` and `fnmatch(3)` -- `opendir()` accepts trailing `/` on a directory, `readdir()` doesn't put a slash on directory names, and `fnmatch()` simply matches patterns without regard to existing files or canonicalization. Specifically, `fnmatch("proc/","proc",0)` returns 1 (no match)..

Compare `rsync` which has very distinct (and well documented) distinctions for trailing / on directory names.

A related issue is that sometimes you want to backup a directory because it's a *mount point*, though you don't want its contents. The intent being your backup can contain all the required mount points (`/dev` `proc` `/sys` ) so usually you would want to do:

```
tar --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/dev/* [...]
```